# Keychain Access Not Returning kSecValueData

Tags: ios, macos, keychain

I'm using the following code:

```
+ (void)createKeychainItem:(NSString *)name
{
    // Don't create if one already exists
    if ([self getKeychainItem:name] != nil) return;

    NSData *encodedName = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{

                                 (id)kSecAttrAccount : encodedName,
                                 (id)kSecAttrGeneric : encodedName,
                                 (id)kSecAttrLabel   : name,
                                 (id)kSecAttrService : name,
                                 (id)kSecClass       : (id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                 };
    OSStatus result = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)attributes, NULL);
}

+ (NSDictionary *)getKeychainItem:(NSString *)name
{
    // Build the query
    NSData *encodedName = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *query = @{
                            (id)kSecAttrAccount : encodedName,
                            (id)kSecAttrGeneric : encodedName,
                            (id)kSecAttrService : name,
                            (id)kSecClass : (id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                            (id)kSecMatchLimit : (id)kSecMatchLimitOne,
                            (id)kSecReturnAttributes : (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                            };
    NSDictionary *output = nil;

    OSStatus result = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&output);

    // Convert the password if it exists
    NSData *passwordData = [output objectForKey:kSecValueData];
    if (passwordData != nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableOutput = [[output mutableCopy] autorelease];
        NSString *password = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:passwordData length:passwordData.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        [mutableOutput setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
        output = [[mutableOutput copy] autorelease];
    }

    return output;
}

+ (void)updateKeychainItem:(NSString *)name value:(NSString *)value attribute:(id)attribute
{
    // Get the item
    NSDictionary *values = [self getKeychainItem:name];

    // If we got nothing back, build it
    if (values == nil) {
        [self createKeychainItem:name];
    }

    // Create a query to update
    NSData *encodedName = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *query = @{
                            (id)kSecAttrAccount : encodedName,
                            (id)kSecAttrGeneric : encodedName,
                            (id)kSecAttrService : name,
                            (id)kSecClass : (id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                            };
    NSDictionary *attributes = nil;
    if (attribute == kSecValueData) {
        attributes = @{ (id)kSecValueData : [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] };
    } else {
        attributes = @{ attribute : value };
    }

    OSStatus result = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFDictionaryRef)attributes);
}
```

Setting a value with `[self updateKeychainItem:AuthTokenIdentifer value:authToken attribute:kSecValueData];` works and I can see it in Keychain Access.

Fetching the results with `NSDictionary *values = [self getKeychainItem:AuthTokenIdentifer];` works, but the kSecValueData is not set in the dictionary.  Everything else is set, like the create and modified dates, just not the secure data.

Any ideas?  This happens on iOS and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the attributes dictionary from getKeychainItem: to fetch the value. Something like

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataQuery = [attrs mutableCopy];
[dataQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
[dataQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

CFTypeRef resultData;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(dataQuery), &resultData);
NSData *tokenData = CFBridgingRelease(resultData);
```